# How do I display a fixed size Views grid regardless of the number of results?

Tags: views

I have a Views grid that can display anywhere from 0 to dozens of results. I want to display a 3 column, 2 row grid with a pager that will always show 6 cells regardless of how many results my filter gives. How do I do that? Also, I can't find the option to display the View even if there are no results. Where is that?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Views responsive grid](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_responsive_grid).  I'd suggest using it over the built in views grid because it splits up your rows/columns in a more manageable way.

The functionality you're looking for is built into views, under pager.  You would need to set it to use a pager as well as display 6 results.

[image]

[image]

The section under Advanced -> No results behavior is what you are looking for.

Comment: This looks promising, but yet again I'm stuck on CSS with something. CSS is killing me on this project. I've put about 200 hours in so far learning Drupal, MySQL, PHP and getting this social networking site working great functionally. The problem is, it looks terrible. I made the switch from Danland to Zen about 3 weeks ago and I still don't understand what Zen is supposed to do. I can't find any tutorials on it, either. I find myself doing all the CSS from scratch and I suck at CSS, so my site looks awful. Does anyone have any links that can help me out? Is Bootstrap something I should learn?

Comment: Zen is a base theme meant to be built upon, you are supposed to do all the css from scratch.  I'd stay away from bootstrap until you learn core CSS.

Comment: Why is Danland 200kB without it's image files, but Zen is over a megabyte? What do all those files in Zen actually do for you? Where do you recommend I learn core CSS? I took the Codeacademy class and if I'm really careful I can build my own HTML layout one div at a time and make it do what I want. When I'm trying to arrange elements deep inside layouts constructed by Drupal's template files, they fight me every step of the way.

Comment: It's just due to the features that zen comes with.  CSS styling itself is just a very small part of any theme.  Honestly, the best way to learn CSS is by just doing it over and over - determine what you want to do and then do it.

Comment: There's a really good tutorial on the Omega theme using SASS here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmTuvzbPduI